# How to show the dropdown menu out of a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the library tabulator and I try to use bootstrap dropdown and I have no clue how to show the dropdown fully or out of the row.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
    height:"100%",
    ajaxURL:"https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1010194405638029312",
    columns:[
    {title:"Report", field:"report_nom"},
    {title:"Last update", field:"report_updatedate", width:300},
    {title:"Action", field:"report_download", formatter:"html", headerSort:false, width:300}
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Here is the full json data :

```
[
  {
    "report_id": 4,
    "report_nom": "Cars",
    "report_description": "Car list",
    "report_frequency": "1",
    "report_filename": "4619082022130005f16de18332f9dab9cbcf6903120837e37762f0c7",
    "access_download": "true",
    "access_id": 3,
    "report_updatedate": "19/08/2022 00:00:09",
    "report_download": "<div style='display: flex'><div class='dropdown'>  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Dropdown button</button><div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Action</a><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Another action</a><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Something else here</a></div></div></div>"
  }
]
```

I tried adding a hight `z-index` but it doesn't fix it.

Result I'm looking for :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work!

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  layout: "fitColumns",
  height: "100%",
  ajaxURL: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1010194405638029312",
  columns: [{
      title: "Report",
      field: "report_nom"
    },
    {
      title: "Last update",
      field: "report_updatedate",
      width: 300
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      field: "report_download",
      formatter: "html",
      headerSort: false,
      width: 300
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#example-table {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-cell {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-tableholder {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```