# How to realign cell from tabulator

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabulator

From the last question I asked [How to show the dropdown menu out of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73418617/how-to-show-the-dropdown-menu-out-of-a-row/73418806#73418806) I wanted to be able to show the dropdown menu.

After adding

```
#example-table {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-cell {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-tableholder {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

My last cell is not on the same row.

[image]

[image]

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  layout: "fitColumns",
  height: "100%",
  ajaxURL: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1010194405638029312",
  columns: [{
      title: "Report",
      field: "report_nom"
    },
    {
      title: "Last update",
      field: "report_updatedate",
      width: 300
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      field: "report_download",
      formatter: "html",
      headerSort: false,
      width: 300
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#example-table {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-cell {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-tableholder {
  overflow: visible !important;
}


.tabulator-row {
    border: 0 !important;
}

.tabulator-row>div {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
}

.tabulator-row>div:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
}

.tabulator-row .tabulator-cell:last-of-type{
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
}

.tabulator-row-even {
    background-color: #FFF !important
}

.tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable:hover {
    background-color: rgba(248, 249, 250, 1) !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:last-of-type>.tabulator-cell:first-of-type {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:last-of-type>.tabulator-cell:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:first-of-type>.tabulator-cell:first-of-type {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:first-of-type>.tabulator-cell:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-col-resize-handle {
    display: none !important
}

.tabulator-cell {
    vertical-align: baseline !important
}

.tabulator,
.tabulator-col {
    background-color: rgba(248, 249, 250, 1) !important;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-header {
    border: 0!important;
}

.tabulator {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-cell {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-tableholder {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator_bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

How can I realign it ?

Comment: the arrow mark in the image is a part of the previous columns, could you do an inspect element and check once? if the problem is there?

Comment: You mean the sort arrow ?

Comment: yes, its seems to be aligned

Comment: Yes but the issue is below, the header is fine

Comment: the html table header will always align with the rows of the table!

Comment: Yes but why the cell below is not aligned with the rest ?

Answer (score 0):

How about aligning all the cells to center vertically using the below css?

```
#example-table .tabulator-cell[tabulator-field="report_download"] {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  layout: "fitColumns",
  height: "100%",
  ajaxURL: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1010194405638029312",
  columns: [{
      title: "Report",
      field: "report_nom"
    },
    {
      title: "Last update",
      field: "report_updatedate",
      width: 300
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      field: "report_download",
      formatter: "html",
      headerSort: false,
      width: 300
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#example-table {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-cell[tabulator-field="report_download"] {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#example-table .tabulator-tableholder {
  overflow: visible !important;
}


.tabulator-row {
    border: 0 !important;
}

.tabulator-row>div {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
}

.tabulator-row>div:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
}

.tabulator-row .tabulator-cell:last-of-type{
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(238, 236, 236) !important;
}

.tabulator-row-even {
    background-color: #FFF !important
}

.tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable:hover {
    background-color: rgba(248, 249, 250, 1) !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:last-of-type>.tabulator-cell:first-of-type {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:last-of-type>.tabulator-cell:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:first-of-type>.tabulator-cell:first-of-type {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-table>.tabulator-row:first-of-type>.tabulator-cell:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px !important;
}

.tabulator-col-resize-handle {
    display: none !important
}

.tabulator-cell {
    vertical-align: baseline !important
}

.tabulator,
.tabulator-col {
    background-color: rgba(248, 249, 250, 1) !important;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-header {
    border: 0!important;
}

.tabulator {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-cell {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-tableholder {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator_bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: Still not aligned :( The overflow parameter is messing the cells

Comment: Still getting the same issue https://i.imgur.com/bXGhS1O.png